# My answer not showing my name

Tags: support, status-bydesign, community-wiki

I wrote an answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416226/my-sister-absolutely-refuses-to-learn-math/416487#416487) question but now it is not showing my name it is showing community wiki and its upvote is also not add in my reputation.

Comment: "its upvote is also not add in my reputation." - CW answers, by design, do not confer reputation on the user. As for your name not showing up: [since most of the edits did not come from you](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/416487/revisions), the name of the editor who contributed the most is what shows up.

Comment: The ol' CW buzzkill$-$ I know it well.  Soon it will hit 100 upvotes, and you will swoon over *what could have been*. :-)

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: if it weren't for the 200 point per day cap.

Answer (score 5):

The [question itself was made community wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/416226/revisions). Read more about [community wiki posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Status.... by design.